# About initialize array with zero

Tags: c, token

error: expected expression before { token

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    
    while(t-->0){
        int m,n,a,b,k;
        int *arr;
        
      scanf("\n%d %d",&n,&m);
     
       arr[n]={ };
     
     
      for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
          
          scanf("\n%d %d %d",&a,&b,&k);
              
    int max=arr[0];
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i]+k;
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max=arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",max);
         
      }
      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in this code, I am initializing the array to zero but it is not working and if I do this also **arr[n]={}** or declare the **array global** then also I got the error.

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: Memory space for `int arr[n] = { };` is allocated at compile time; therefore, n needs to be an integer literal. It may not be a variable. Either set it to a maximum using preprocessor `#define NMAX 100` or use `malloc` to allocate memory.

Comment: @ssd incorrect.

Comment: Please **provide the actual error message with the line number** and **tell what compiler you're using**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : My previous attempts for `int arr[n] = { };` returned *"error: variable-sized object may not be initialized"*.

Comment: @ssd yes, the initialization fails, not the array itself. So what is the problem now, you've got a VLA that needs to be initialized to zero? Use memset.

Comment: in ** int arr[n] ** in this line sir and I am using gcc with vs code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I saw on certain implementations even the non-VLAs initialization is performed using a variant of `memset` under the hood, so not sure why this limitation present.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : Sorry, you're correct! `int arr[n] = { };` fails to compile but `int arr[n];` compiles cleanly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well, I don't get it either, it should be possible to provide initializers and excess initializers would be ignored, and extra elements zeroed :D

Comment: It is one of the worst things to edit out the problems in your code after asking the question based on the original code.  When you do this, you invalidate the comments and answers people have donated their time to provide by making the whole question a moving target.  Please do not do this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because problems being originally asked about were edited out of the post by owner, thus nullifying the original questions, comments and answers.

Comment: I am rolling back this question to it's original version. Please post a new question for further help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `n` is defined as a *variable*, there are two problems with the following statement:

```
int arr[n]={ };
```

The error on my system states
`error: use of GNU empty initializer extension`

If this were *not a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)*, the problem could be addressed by providing an initializer:

```
#define n 10 //used to size a non-VLA array
...
int arr[n]={0}; //Uses constant array size, not variable,  thus can be initialized normally.
```

But it *is* a VLA, leading to the next issue, incorrect use of VLA, where the error states:
`error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`

Both issues can be addressed with following:

```
int arr[n];
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
```

One final suggestion is to check the return value for the [scanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) statement:

```
scanf("\n%d %d",&n,&m);
```

To ensure the correct number of items have been processed before assuming `n`.

```
int count = scanf("\n%d %d",&n,&m);
if(count == 2)
{
    int arr[n];
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr);  
    ....
```

Comment: The "empty initializer" could be avoided by using `{0}`. However, this would just produce the "variable-sized object may not be initialized" error!

Comment: `sizeof(int())`?

Comment: @IanAbbott - LOL, Thanks!  (addressed both of your comments I hope.)

Comment: .. or simply `memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);`

Comment: @ryyker There is still one `sizeof(int())` left over in the final code section that you forgot to edit. Interestingly, GCC thinks `sizeof(int())` is 1!

Comment: @IanAbbott - got it.  Thanks.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This works but how and what does that mean ? and also Thanks all of you to gave your precious time .

Comment: @TheGentelmen24 - Chux is pointing out that for int arr[n];` the statement `n*sizeof(int)` is equivalent to `sizeof arr`, or`sizeof(arra0`.

Comment: @ryyker sir I am newbie in c language so that I don't understand that when and how this **memset **works?

Comment: @TheGentelmen24 -  [memset](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm) is an alternative way to initialize all of the elements of an object, such as your VLA `arr`. since in the case,  `arr` is a VLA, it cannot be initialized in the more common way of `int arr[n] = {0};`  So `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));` sets all memory locations of array `arr` to `0`.

Comment: @TheGentelmen24 `memset` just sets a block of bytes to a particular value. It can be used for setting an array of `int` to all elements 0 because an `int` object with all bytes zero will be interpreted as the `int` value 0. (That is not necessarily true for other types such as `float`.)

Answer (score 1):

`arr[n]={ };` here is an assignment, not an initialization. You are assigning the element at index `n` in the array. To initialize an array, you need to make this a declaration: `int array[n];`.

Comment: But like int arr[n]={ }; this we can initialize array with zero so what's the problem?

Comment: @TheGentelmen24 The problem is you don't have `int arra[n] = {}` instead you have `arr[n] = {}`. These are two different things.

Comment: OP edited the original code causing this whole thing to be a moving target.

Comment: This addresses the original content of the question. +1.  (I didn't even show up until question content had been edited, so was not aware until I looked more carefully at your post.)